# Updating an object via context in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am struggling to declare context with typescript and react. According to the [react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#examples-basic), you can pass your `setEconomy` action to the `EconomyContext.Provider` component. However, the value tag on that component will only accept `economy` as input and not as declared below an object `{ economy, setEconomy }`.

How can I declare my state with the option to update the state in a nested component?

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Economy from './model/Economy';

const defaultEconomy: Economy = {
    households: [],
    simulationId: '',
};
export const EconomyContext = createContext<Economy>(defaultEconomy);

export const ContextProviders: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    const [economy, setEconomy] = useState(defaultEconomy);
    return <EconomyContext.Provider value={{ economy, setEconomy }}>{props.children}</EconomyContext.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createContext<Economy>(defaultEconomy)
```

When you created the context, you told typescript that the value would be an `Economy`. But then when you try to provide the value later on, you're passing in a more complex object, which has both an economy property and a setEconomy property. To do that, create your context something like this:

```
export const EconomyContext = createContext<{
  economy: Economy;
  setEconomy: (newEconomy: Economy) => void;
}>({ 
  economy: defaultEconomy, 
  setEconomy: () => {} 
});
```